# Replace successively repeating sub-sequences by fewer of them

Tags: replacement

Imagine I have a complicated sequence {....,a1,a2,a3,...,x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2,....,z1,z2,z3,...}

I want to replace the repeating pattern x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2,x1,x2 (which could be anything more than two - here it is four repetitions) by just x1,x2 or separately by x1,x2,x1,x2.

I tried SequenceReplace but was not successful.

```
SequenceReplace[{Repeated[PatternSequence[x1, x2], {2, Infinity}], 
e_} -> Union[{ x1, x2 }, e ]]@{x1, x2, x1, x2, x1, x2, x3, x4}
```

did not work..

Comment: Does `SequenceReplace[{x1, x2, x1, x2, x1, x2, x3, x4}, {PatternSequence[x1, x2] .. } -> Splice[{x1, x2}]]` suit your needs?

Comment: This shows many syntax errors

Comment: It works on 12.1 in the Cloud; this is a little harder to do in earlier versions.

Comment: I have 12.0. Are you sure this is literal? 
    PatternSequence[x1, x2] ..

Comment: Yes, look at `FullForm[PatternSequence[x1, x2] ..]` to see what it looks like.

Comment: Does this work without any problems in every version: `somelist//.{h___,x1,x2,x1,x2,t___}->{h,x1,x2,t}`

Comment: @J.M.  Here is the error message.                                                                                                                               
    `Splice::string: String expected at position 1 in Splice[{x1,x2}]`.                                                                                                                                                                                                          
       `Out[21]={Splice[{x1, x2}], x3, x4}`

Comment: @Quasar, [`Splice[]` was changed in 12.1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Splice.html). Try this: `SequenceReplace[{x1, x2, x1, x2, x1, x2, x3, x4}, {PatternSequence[x1, x2] ..} -> Unevaluated[Sequence[x1, x2]]]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[seqReplace, removeRepeats]

seqReplace = SequenceReplace[{Repeated[p : PatternSequence[_, ___], {2, ∞}]} :> p];

removeRepeats = FixedPoint[seqReplace, #] &
```

***Examples:***

```
lst1 = {x1, x2, x1, x2, x1, x2, a, b, b, b, x3, x2, x1, x3, x2, x1, x1, x1, x1};

removeRepeats @ lst1
```

> ```
>  {x1, x2, a, b, x3, x2, x1}
> ```

```
lst2 = {x1, x1, x2, x1, x2, x2, x2, x1, x2, a, b, b, x3, x2, x1, x3, x2, x1, x1, x1, x1};

removeRepeats @ lst2
```

> ```
>  {x1, x2, a, b, x3, x2, x1}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following using [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html):

```
pattremove = 
  ReplaceRepeated[{start___, x1_, x2_, x1_, x2_, end___} :> {start, x1, x2, end}];

pattremove@{a1, a2, a3, x1, x2, x1, x2, x1, x2, x1, x2, x1, x2, z1, z2}
(* Out: {a1, a2, a3, x1, x2, z1, z2} *)

pattremove@{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7}
(* Out: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)

pattremove@{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7}
(* Out: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)
```